# Codeigniter Nginx Controller Functions Returning 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, nginx

I am currently running nginx and codeigniter on my server.
I can access the base functions,for example

**sample.dev/samplecontroller**

but when i try to specify a function within that controller,e.g

**sample.dev/controller/function**

I get 404 error

My sites-available file for the project sample.dev is as follows:

```
server {
listen 80 ;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/html/sample_ci;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name sample.dev;

      location / {
           # URLs to attempt, including pretty ones.
           try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
   error_page 404 /404.html;
   error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
   location = /50x.html {
     root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
#   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    try_files $uri =404;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
#
#   # With php5-cgi alone:
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

            include                        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

My .htaccess file for the project is also as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sample_ci

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /HCMP/index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

And i have configured the config.php file variables as follows:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://sample.dev/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

The above configuration is not functional despite me following all steps on the official nginx site and on the other posts I have found here.
Is there anything im doing wrong or should do?

Comment: Solved it!

Added the following to my /etc/nginx.conf
    **httpd{
        fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    }**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use .htaccess files on nginx... those files are mostly for Apache. Therefore, your rewrites are not being used and you will always get a 404.

What you need to know is here:

```
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/#
http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-nginx-rewrite-rules/
```